# How to Rank User Profiles using profile characteristics

Tags: search, web-crawler, profile, rank

I am wondering how I would go about ranking my websites user profiles on certain characteristics: such as keywords withing profile sections, and sign up form answers...

Any Ideas on where to begin?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to rank a user profile, then you better to use other user profile's specifications as a parameter to help you in raking. I don't know which websites you are using to rank, but I will assume that you want to rank all websites user profiles. So you can use these specifications generally:

- If the web site gives the user some points per posts like **stackoverflow.com** so you can rank user profiles according to the points they have got.
- You can use "Number of profile seen by other user" to rank too.
- Also, you can use "Number of Posts Published by the User".
- "User availability per day or month"

I hope these issues can you help while ranking user profiles.